# Storing columns from a text file in an array

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a range of data. My data consists of 49 variables and I want to split this into 7. I have my data stored in a text file consisting of two rows of x and y as following:
[image]

I want to split both rows by 7 and create an x,y plot so that it gives me seven lines on my graph. I tried doing this:

```
lines = f.readlines()
lines1 = lines1[0:6]
lines2 = lines2[7:14]
lines3 = lines3[15:21]
lines4 = lines4[21:28]
lines5 = lines5[28:35]
lines6 = lines6[35:42]
lines7 = lines7[43:49]
```

I would then put all of the above data in an array and the same process for the y values as well. Finally, I would plot the variables. But this is inefficient and requires alot of time. There must be an easier way, but I cannot think of it. Could someone help?

[image: Wrong plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NumPy's `loadtxt` to read the data and then use a for loop to plot the x and the y coordinates in batches of 7. Below is a sample answer. Just replace `sample.txt` by your actual file name (including the directory where the file is located).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.loadtxt('sample.txt', unpack=True)

for i in range(0, 49, 7):
    plt.plot(x[i:i+7], y[i:i+7])

plt.show()
```

**EDIT** Adding labels

```
for lab, i in enumerate(range(0, 49, 7)):
    plt.plot(x[i:i+7], y[i:i+7], label='group %d' %lab)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: There seems to be an issue:  ticks = np.arange(low, high + 1) * step + best_vmin + offset

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: @Mason : What is this low and high and all these variables? You do realize that if you just provide half information without the details of what is going wrong on your screen, what data you are using, what code you are using etc., there is no way for me or any other person to find out the error. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand what you mean? I just tried your code with my file but it returns with the above error. I don't have a clue what the error implies.

Comment: @Mason : There is no `ticks = np.arange(low, high + 1) * step + best_vmin + offset` in my code. Where is this line coming from? Can you include the exact code which gives you this error in your question?

Comment: This is what shows up in my console:  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 1937, in _raw_ticks
    ticks = np.arange(low, high + 1) * step + best_vmin + offset

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>

Comment: @Mason: Try restarting your kernel and see if the error still persists. I am unaware of this error

Comment: Restarting the kernel worked. Thanks! However, it seems like it did not plot my data as the line is linear. I have added an image of the graph in my original post. It didn't plot my data at all. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @Mason: What is your expected output? How does your data inside the file look like? Can you include some data in your question.

Comment: @Mason: You see, that's the problem. Your question says "two rows of x and y" but what you actually have is two columns. I will modify my answer but from next time, make sure you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I apolgize for that, I should have been clearer. I appreciate your effort. Thanks again.

Comment: I should have asked this last night, but how would I add labels to my data? I now have seven different lines on the same graph. I want to assign a label to each of those lines. I apologize asking you this, but I forgot so last night.

Comment: @Mason : Edited.